# Get array of user IDs from multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I've the following array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 1
        [more_user_data] => More
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 2
        [more_user_data] => More 
    )

)
```

Now I want to have a comma separated list of the IDs to use them in an own array. To get something like this:

`array(1,2)`

How could I only extract the IDs from the second array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `array_column()` function like:

```
$arr = array_column($array, 'ID');
```

[Working Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/990662afabe0b8e8ab38bba7fc9728f0eaa81fa1)

Comment: works like a charm. thanks a lot!!